# Function to find the xy location of a pixel

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

Since my previous question was certainly not very clean. And respectively i couldn't implement an exact solution of my problem. I have been working on a function that returns the byte offset of a pixel located in X/Y coords. For that purpose i have that:

```
dword bmp_find_xy (dword xp, dword yp)
{
    dword w = 50; // to clarify thats the real widh of the sample image i use
    dword bpx = (3*8); // using 3*8 as a reminder.
    dword offset = (2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB)); // this is the offset 54.
    dword pitch = w * 3; // determining the widh of pixels. Pitch variable
    dword row = w * 3; // determining the widh of pixels. Row variable.
    dword pixAddress; // result variable

    if(pitch % 4 != 0) pitch += 4 - (pitch % 4); // finding the pitch (row+padding)
    pixAddress = (offset) + pitch * yp + ((xp * bpx) / 8); // finding the address

    return pixAddress; 
}
```

So the question won't be like "What am i doing wrong/why im receiving weird errors". The question is.. am i doing it correct? On first tests it seems to work. But i am somehow unsure. Once it is confirmed thats the correct way.. I'll delete the question.

Comment: I need a class on bitmap theory because I certainly don't know enough to help you.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It is easy but it is just really confusing.
And by the way i am not native speaking.. which makes it even worse.
And no.. its just that i can't post the entire project. Noone will be able to compile it. It is for a custom engine.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that you weren't a native English speaker so... nothing to worry there. :-D

Comment: I am doing my best...

Comment: You're hard-coding `pitch` but have this statement: `if(pitch % 4 != 0) ...;`.  This will always be true because 150 is not evenly divisible by 4.

Comment: What's a good link to a bitmap page to help us visualize what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Simply.. i call the function like that:
`bmp_find_xy(0,0);` which returns the offset of the first pixel. (starts from bottom left of the image)
Doing so i can easy put a pixel there.

Comment: I think thats really useful function. So if it works correct i can use her everywhere. Right now im working on a finding a pixel by color (first occurance).. which requires that function to work properly.

Comment: I think the function has to work correct. Because.. the `bmp_find_bycolor` or aka `bmp_dfind_c` works correct now. On any tests. Shall i edit the question and post an example useful usage of this function?

Comment: Maybe a link to a simplified description of bitmap files?

Comment: Well i have been studdying from here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: "Why im receiving weird errors". What "weird errors" are you talking about? Where are you receiving them from?

Comment: I am not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like it gives the correct result to me. However it is inconsistent in itself.

- In the row (yp) addressing, you assume that every pixel has 3 bytes.
- In the column (xp) addressing, you assume that every pixel has 3*8 bits.

So why use bytes in the first case, bits in the second case? I think the code would be cleaner like this:

```
dword width = 50; // image width
dword channels = 3; // number of color channels
dword bpp = 8; // depth in bits

dword single = (channels*bpp)/8; // size of a pixel in bytes
dword offset = (2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB)); // this is the offset 54.
dword rowsize = width*single; // size of a row in memory
if (rowsize % 4 != 0)
    rowsize += 4 - (rowsize % 4); // account for padding

dword pixAddress; // result variable
pixAddress = offset + yp*rowsize + xp*single; // finding the address

return pixAddress;
```

Also, you can read the width, channel and bpp from the header.

Next, your code would be faster if you get the address of the first pixel in a row first, then keep it to iterate through the row (not recompute the whole thing every time). Here is an illustration of a typical task running over all pixels. Note that I do not use the same coding style as in the original question here.

```
unsigned char maxGreen = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    unsigned char *row = bitmap.getRowPtr(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        unsigned char *pixel = row + bitmap.getColumnOffset(x);
        if (pixel[2] > maxGreen)
            maxGreen = pixel[2];
    }
}
// maxGreen holds the maximum value in the green channel observed in the image
```

As you can see, in this example the offset, padding etc. calculations only need to be done once per row in the getRowPtr() function. Per pixel we only need to do the offset calculation (a simple multiplication) in the getColumnOffset() function.
This makes the example much faster, when breaking down how many calculations need to be done per pixel.

Last, I would never write code to read a BMP myself! Use a library for that!

Comment: i have a reason for this. I am not reading the values from the header because i removed that to make it simple in here. And i can't use a library, because there is noone compatible to the engine im using. Thats why im making my own. +1 for the confirmation and the suggestion. However.. I couldn't understand the thing with the code where it beings faster.

Comment: Most times you operate on a bitmap you go through all the pixels. For example, you have a for loop over yp around a for loop over xp. In this case, it would be wise to fetch the start of a row in the outer loop and use that as a base in the inner loop.